# How to determine if a problem is solvable by analytic methods?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am frequently coming across problems which are not susceptible to analytic methods.

This has often been frustrating as I have been unable to predetermine if my time would be wasted with such methods.

Is there a theory behind which problems are solvable by analytic methods and which are not?

An example of such a problem I've come across was the following:

*"Find a real solution to the equation $n=(1+1/n)^n$ "*

Answer (score 1):

According to Wolfy,
the result is
$n \approx 2.293...$.

For a start,
if a problem involves
the solution of
$x e^x = a$
for $x$ in terms of $a$,
this can not be exactly solved
(except by using the
Lambert W function,
which is sort of cheating).

In your case,
I would play around
and see if
I could get an
initial approximation.

$1+1/n
=n^{1/n}
=e^{\log n/n}
\approx 1+\log n/n + \log^2(n)/(2n^2)+\text{ higher order terms}
$,
so,
as a first approximation,
$\log n = 1$,
or
$n = e$.

For the next approximation,
$1
=\log n+\log^2 n/(2n)
$,
and already this is a pain.

From these initial explorations,
I would guess that
no analytic expression
could be found for the root.

Comment: "For a start, if a problem involves the solution of xe x =a xex=a for x x in terms of a a, this can not be exactly solved.." These sorts of conclusive statements are what I was referring to in my question. How did you determine this?

Comment: Look up the Lambert W function.

Comment: @martycohen How would one solve using Lambert W when there is $x^x$ involved?

Answer (score 0):

> *Find a real solution to the equation $n=(1+1/n)^n$.*

This is the [second Foias constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoiasConstant.html), whose decimal expansion can be found [here](http://oeis.org/A085846).